# How to find maximum of numpy array around axis = 0, excluding tuples of 0s?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

I have a numpy array, r, that is 3 x 2048 X 2048. I have the following code to find the max of r with axis= 0.

```
maximum = r.max(axis=0)
```

How can I accomplish the same task as above but exclude the tuples of 0s (black pixels), when finding the max?

Comment: What do you mean by `tuples of 0s`? Produce a [`mcve`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question as follows: your image-like array may contain for one pixel the value `[0,0,0]` and if this occurs, you do not want to include this in the finding of the maximum. Or put differently: you do not want a value of zero in `maximum`.

If that is what you want, then you can just mask out all zeros like this:

```
maximum = r.max(axis=0) # maximum has shape (2048, 2048)
maximum = maximum[maximum>0] # now maximum is 1d with length 2048^2-(number of "black pixels")
```